# Did they break King Dedede's infinite combo?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Before I start doing this question, I will explain King Dedede's infinite combo (for those who do not know it).

If you use King Dedede's basic A attack to the second swing, then wait, only to re-attack with it (but not soon enough after to do the spin or the finisher), the player can re-activate the basic A for the first two hits before the enemy can move. This happens because King Dedede's second hit in his basic A set pulls enemies to him. AND, with the right distance and timing, King Dedede can do an infinite combo on all of the characters that are not very light.

But, every time I have used it, the enemy was able to get out of it before I could rack up heavy damage (on the occasions, I was fighting: Bowser, Mario, Kirby (I guessed he would escape), Zelda, and Ike). Did Nintendo break the combo from working against anything but a potato, or do I just need to practice it more?

I say anything but a potato because it was able to work against an enemy in training set to stop.

Note: All of the battles I mentioned were on For Glory: 1 vs 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's [still possible.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sithdTac4Bg&feature=youtu.be&hd=1)

However, there's [talk of it](http://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/2vtj8b/) only working against players of questionable skill.

> DOES NOT WORK AGAINST COMPETENT PLAYERS
>   This only works against retarded AI. Nothing to see here.

However,

> You won't get 0-160% no, but you can definitely string a few hits together.

So as an answer, you can definitely combo it, just not infinitely.

Comment: So instead of trying to go for a high hit combo, I should just deal a couple of sets, then go for a finisher without risking them getting out?

Comment: Exactly. It works a lot like a grab, really. Grab then, get 2-3 hits in, then throw before they can break out.